# Thousand separator for list_editable in django?

Tags: django, django-admin

*Is there a thousand separator (like 1,000) for list_editable in django?

```
#model.py
class Product(models.Model):
deal_price = models.IntegerField(db_index=True, blank=True, null=True, default=0, validators=[position], verbose_name=_("Current Price"))

-//-

class StockProduct(Product):
    category = models.ForeignKey(to=StockCategory, related_name='stock_products')
    warehouse = models.ForeignKey(to=WareHouse, blank=True, null=True)

    objects = ProductManager()

#admin.py
class StockProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = StockProductAdminForm
    list_display = ('product_id', 'title', 'quantity', 'category', 'deal_price_sep')
    list_editable = ('quantity', 'deal_price_sep')

def deal_price_sep(self, instance):
        return '{0:,}'.format(self.deal_price)

admin.site.register(models.StockProduct, StockProductAdmin)
```

Whenever I change deal_price_sep to deal_price, it works. But I want the list_editable show price with thousand separator.

Comment: What would a thousand separator be doing in list_editable?

Comment: Price of products (integer number)

Answer (score 1):

In case anybody also wants to display more big numbers:

Add to the default settings in the your settings file (e.g. settings.py):

```
USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = True
```

[Source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR)

Comment: This is actually a bad option, because it will add the separator to any number, so you will have year, width, height, etc... with separators, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: I agree with Jose's comment. This approach is not good. If this option is available in model level, then it will be better.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but I think you should be able to do:

```
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_editable = ('foo_thousand',)
    list_display = ('foo_thousand',)

    def foo_thousand(self, instance):
        return '{0:,}'.format(self.foo)
```

But then you will probably need to strip out the chars that are not digits before you save. You could do that in the `save_model()` method.

Comment: foo_thousand is not direct attribute of Person model. I am afraid it does not work. It works only when there is no list_display. Once we add list_display it becomes useless.

Comment: Yeah you need to replace foo with whatever field name you want to use. In order to use `list_editable`, you need to specify the same field in `list_display`. Maybe you are just confusing everybody. You should probably be more specific with letting us know what it is you want to do.

Comment: I have added the code. As Django documentation says field name should be in list_display. In my case I am running function 'deal_price_sep'. I think I should override defaut admin form, else it does not work.

Comment: The problem of this approach is that I cannot use list sorting in admin list.