# Display editable decimal field with trailing currency symbol in admin interface (Django)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have a simple model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ...
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
    ...

    def price_currency(self):
        return '%.2f €' % self.price
```

And admin model:

```
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['price_currency']
```

Achieves this list overview of products (only price column screenshot):

[image]

The problem is that this field is not editable (in list view). Is there a way to make it editable and display the trailing currency symbol at the end?

I can just call `list_display = ['price']` and `list_editable = ['price']`, the problem is that then it does not show the euro sign at the end, ie:

[image]

My ideal end goal would be:

[image]

Comment: You can show the currency sign on top like: `Price (€)`.

Comment: Please refer to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32715884/thousand-separator-for-list-editable-in-django
create a custom function to show the currency.

Comment: why are you not trying list_editable=['price_currency']

Comment: That does not work because 'price_currency' returns a string for each object... In either case, I will go along with @xyres's suggestion of making the column header `Price (€)`