# Django: Replacing comma with dot as a decimal separator while keeping localization

Tags: python, django, localization

I have built a multi-lingual website with django. My problem is that when the user changes localization all floats turn from dot-based to comma-based (e.g. the "4.2" become "4,2").

I have created a template filter that replaces comma separators with dots in order to handle this situation but I think it is not the best solution as there are many places that use floats.

Can I do that on the back-end while keeping all other localization settings?

Comment: I had a similar issue over a year ago in the django admin (see [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48545392/thousand-separator-not-applied-in-django-admin)); I don't have a good solution, just a workaround using a custom template filter, probably very similar to your solution.